# Differences between RESTful API and urlpatterns router in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Am new to web developpement and wondering the differences between:

Django Restful API

and

standard Django URL routers

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='Index'),
    url(r'^getvalue/$', views.get_points, name='Get Points'),
    url(r'^putvalue/$', views.put_points, name='Put Points'),
]
```

What are the benefits of setting Django restful API when interacting with Javascript components since both are JSON sending URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Before understanding this you have know that,

- REST API concept.
- HTTP verbs(REQUEST METHOD)

**REST API**

REST API is nothing but very special. Just remember one thing this is a concept where we can use proper use of HTTP VERBS. Like, `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS` etc....

**HTTP VERBS**

I already told you the names of HTTP VERBS. Think what we do normally?? Basically I do, I use POST for updating db row, I use POST for DELETE a row. But in REST API concept we can't do like this kinds of nasty things. When we are going to delete something we need to use `DELETE`

**Links**

You may read this, https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: what are the advantage over DJANGO_URL routers ?

Comment: If you are talking about DRF router and Django Url then both are fine. Django url patterns is more descriptive than DRF router and DRF router basically used for quick and small configuration. Whenever you are using django and DRF together you may use Django URL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was quite some time since the question had been asked, but I thought I'd provide an answer as it bothered me as well.

The main reason why you want to use Django's routers is convenience: once you declared them once, you don't have to go through the same cumbersomeness as persistent declaration of urls in urls_patterns.

However, the url_patterns can still be used if for any reason you want to have a specific hard-coded url.