# Using Router vs including url in urlpatterns

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-react

Say I am creating a Todo app in Django, traditionally I would include a path to my app in the base_project urls.py file. However, today I came across a tutorial where they used a router for this same purpose I've already stated.
Why would I want to use a Router instead of including the path in my urls.py file?
For reference, here is a snip from the tutorial found at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react

```
 # backend/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include                 # add this
from rest_framework import routers                    # add this
from todo import views                            # add this

router = routers.DefaultRouter()                      # add this
router.register(r'todos', views.TodoView, 'todo')     # add this

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),         path('api/', include(router.urls))                # add this
]
```

Here backend is the main django project name.

Comment: This Could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184551/differences-between-restful-api-and-urlpatterns-router-in-django

Answer (score 1):

Both works the same. You can add url in the urlpatterns. I had the same situation as yours where in a tutorial they were using routing instead of url patteren but i studied and both works the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).